# Prevent CSS animation repeated on Gatsby Hydration

Tags: javascript, css, gatsby, styled-components

In gatsby I have an element, which has an initial css animation.

It starts playing nicely when the static site loads, but after hydration it repeats.

Is there any way to prevent it?

Here is my style (I used styled-components):

```css
const Container = styled.main<{fontSize:number}>`
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      background-position-y: -100px;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
      background-position-y: 0px;
    }
  }
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2em;
  min-height: 330px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  font-size: ${(props) => props.fontSize + "px"};
  background: ${(props) => props.theme.backgroundImage};
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: -100px;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 715px;
  ${media.mobile`
    background-size: 100vw;
  `}

  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix your your CSS selector with a class `.no-js`. When server renders page the class is "on" by default, for example `<body class="no-js">`.

Your selector would then look like:

```css
.no-js .my-element {
    /* animation */
}
```

Or in case of a styled component,

```css
body.no-js & {
    /* animation */
}
```

Then, use JavaScript in your component to remove the `.no-js` class after hydration.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.remove('no-js');
}, []);
```

Comment: The idea was great, but apparently when I remove the class the whole animation is terminated and I ended up in the final state :(

Comment: I see. In that case, try the opposite?